# Can not debug magento 2 use phpstorm with xdebug

Tags: magento2, debug, phpstorm, xdebug

When I try to debug magento2 by `phpstorm` and `xdebug` I got this error:

> /opt/lampp/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req
>   -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_sample Testing started at 17:45 ...
>   -#!/opt/lampp/bin/php
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\WebapiAbstract' not found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_sample/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/Bundle/Api/CartItemRepositoryTest.php
>   on line 10

PHP Stack trace:

```
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:0
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\WebapiAbstract' not
>   found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_sample/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/Bundle/Api/CartItemRepositoryTest.php
>   on line 10

PHP   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:250
Call Stack:

> 2.1859     457720   1. {main}() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:0PHP   3. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::loadByAutoloader($path = *uninitialized*)
>   /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:173

PHP   4. require_once() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:246

> 2.3308     457720   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:250

PHP   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main($exit = *uninitialized*) /opt/lampp/bin/phpunit:46

> 2.3308     457720   3. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::loadByAutoloader(???) /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:173
>
> ```
> 2.3311     460480   4. require_once('/opt/lampp/bin/phpunit') /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:246
> ```

PHP   6. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run($argv = *uninitialized*, $exit = *uninitialized*) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:126

> ```
> 2.3349     690272   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main(???) /opt/lampp/bin/phpunit:46
> ```

PHP   7. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest($suiteClassName = *uninitialized*, $suiteClassFile = *uninitialized*) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:145

> 2.3349     690368   6. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(???, ???) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:126

PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles($filenames = *uninitialized*) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:96

> 2.3385     852992   7. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest(???, ???) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:145

PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile($filename = *uninitialized*, $phptOptions = *uninitialized*) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:419

> 23.8450    2452624   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles(???) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:96

PHP  10. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad($filename = *uninitialized*) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:358

> 23.8450    2452624   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile(???, ???) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:419

PHP  11. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load($filename = *uninitialized*) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:79

PHP  12. include_once() /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:95

> 23.8648    2508240  10. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad(???) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:358
>
> 23.8648    2508400  11. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load(???) /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:79
>
> 23.8732    2551800  12. include_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_sample/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/Bundle/Api/CartItemRepositoryTest.php')
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:95

Process finished with exit code 255